# Emacs initialization as org file: how can I get the right version of org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've been experimenting with the [org-babel tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#literate-programming) that describes how to put the bulk of your emacs init.el file into an org file. However, I would like to use org-mode 8 (mainly for the new exporter) and I'm on gnu emacs 24.3.1 (for windows) which comes with org-mode 7.9 built-in, so I have org-mode installed from the [elpa package manager](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html) instead of using the built-in version.

My problem is that emacs loads the org-mode that comes with emacs rather than the one I have installed in elpa. Is there a way to load the elpa org-mode?

Here is my init.el, modified from the org-babel tutorial to point (I thought) to my org-mode distribution - but my emacs-lisp knowledge is minimal so I don't really know what it is doing.

```
;;; From http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#literate-programming
;;; init.el --- Where all the magic begins
;;
;; This file loads Org-mode and then loads the rest of our Emacs initialization from Emacs lisp
;; embedded in literate Org-mode files.
;; Load up Org Mode and (now included) Org Babel for elisp embedded in Org Mode files
(setq dotfiles-dir (file-name-directory (or (buffer-file-name) load-file-name)))
(let* ((org-dir (expand-file-name
             "elpa" (expand-file-name
                     "org-plus-contrib-20130624" )))
  (org-contrib-dir (expand-file-name
                     "lisp" (expand-file-name
                             "contrib" (expand-file-name
                                        ".." org-dir))))
       (load-path (append (list org-dir org-contrib-dir)
                      (or load-path nil))))
  ;; load up Org-mode and Org-babel
  (require 'org-install)
  (require 'ob-tangle))

;; load up all literate org-mode files in this directory
(mapc #'org-babel-load-file (directory-files dotfiles-dir t "\\.org$"))

;;; init.el ends here
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put `(package-initialize)` before any calls to `org-babel-load-file` or any other Org function, and you'll get the ELPA version.

Comment: Actually you have to make sure `(package-initialize)` comes before any calls to any `Org` function with autoloads.  That's likely to be `org-babel-load-file` but not guaranteed.

Comment: This worked a treat. I put (package-initialize) at the beginning of my init.el and org-mode 8 is loaded.

Comment: If you use a method other than `package.el`, this may not work, and so you might edit `load-path` as below, for instance if you `git clone` a bleeding edge org to some arbitrary directory of your choosing; simply adding the `load-path` won't work, you have to remove the builtin org from `load-path`. I think I used something like Alex Vorobiev's answer. Only if I need to test the bleeding edge for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I use same kind of initialization and recently did two major changes:

- Changed to https://github.com/dimitri/el-get based packaging management
- upgraded to org-mode > 8.0

Here's how my init.el looks now,

https://github.com/d4gg4d/my-emacs/blob/master/init.el

Also,

- I removed .deb packaged org-mode which came with ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Though already solved and only somewhat related, I thought I would offer this for those who don't use package-based solutions but need to unload things like org and cedet/semantic, etc. without restarting emacs.

In general for unloading a set of features based on a starting name regexp, I would do something like this - which seems more complete than the hardcoded version from Andreas' answer, which doesn't seem to cover all loaded org features (at least in my case).

`load-history` is a massive assoc list of files -> reqs,provides,defuns,...

```lisp
(mapc
 #'(lambda (f) (and (featurep f) (unload-feature f t)))
 (loop for file-syms in load-history
       for prov = (assoc 'provide file-syms)
       with features
       if (and prov (string-match "^org" (symbol-name (cdr prov)))) 
       collect (cdr prov) into features
       finally return features))
```

Replace the regexp `"^org"` to suit your needs, or go wild and make it a defun.

This could also be modified to grab all loaded org features from `load-history`, unload them, add the new load-path, and reload those same features from the new location.

Comment: Thanks! Being well aware my approach wasn't that smart :)

Comment: On the contrary!  Your approach & answer was my so far =)

Answer (score 2):

I configure package repositories in an org-based configuration file as well, so, to adjust the load path I have this in my init.el prior to loading org:

```
;; remove org-mode shipped with emacs from the load-path
(setq custom-org-path (car (file-expand-wildcards
                            (concat my-init-dir "elpa/org-plus-contrib-20*")))) 
(when custom-org-path 
  (setq load-path (remove-if (lambda (x) (string-match-p "org$" x)) load-path))

  (add-to-list 'load-path custom-org-path))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unloaded shipped org-mode and installed development version this way

```
(defun unload-org-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (and (featurep 'org-agenda)(unload-feature 'org-agenda t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-bbdb)(unload-feature 'org-bbdb t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-bibtex)(unload-feature 'org-bibtex t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-compat)(unload-feature 'org-compat t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-exp)(unload-feature 'org-exp t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-exp-blocks)(unload-feature 'org-exp-blocks t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-faces)(unload-feature 'org-faces t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-footnote)(unload-feature 'org-footnote t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-gnus)(unload-feature 'org-gnus t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-html)(unload-feature 'org-html t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-info)(unload-feature 'org-info t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-infojs)(unload-feature 'org-infojs t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-irc)(unload-feature 'org-irc t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-jsinfo)(unload-feature 'org-jsinfo t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-list)(unload-feature 'org-list t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-macs)(unload-feature 'org-macs t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-mew)(unload-feature 'org-mew t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-mhe)(unload-feature 'org-mhe t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-rmail)(unload-feature 'org-rmail t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-src)(unload-feature 'org-src t ))
  (and (featurep 'org-vm)(unload-feature 'org-vm t))
  (and (featurep 'org-w3m)(unload-feature 'org-w3m t))
  (and (featurep 'org-wl)(unload-feature 'org-wl t )))

(defun ar-load-PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (unload-org-mode)
  (find-file "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/lisp/ob-python.el")
  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode")
  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/lisp")
  (load "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/lisp/ob-comint.el" nil t)
  (load "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/lisp/ob-emacs-lisp.el" nil t)
  (load "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/lisp/org.el" nil t)
  (load "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/lisp/ob-eval.el" nil t)
  (load "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/lisp/ob.el" nil t)
  (load "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/lisp/ob-python.el")
  ;; (load "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/testing/org-test-ob-consts.el" nil t)
  ;; (load "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/testing/org-test.el" nil t)
  (load-this-directory "~/PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode/lisp")
    (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '(
     (sh . t)
     (python . t)
     (emacs-lisp . t)
     (perl . t)
     (R . t)
     ))
)

(ar-load-PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode)
```

Replace `PATH-TO-NEW-org-mode` with the directory your version whished resides.