# Emacs sees the directory with the new org-mode version, but loads the old version

Tags: org-mode

The version of `org-mode` that came with my version of `Emacs` (24.5.2) is `8.2.10`. I have installed version `8.3.1` from ELPA and added this to my init file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/org-20150803")
(require 'org)
```

When I check the version of `org` in Emacs, it says:

> Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /home/meir/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20150803/)

That is, it reports the old version and the new directory... (the built-in version is located in `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/org`)

I have tried the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20616703/2725810) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17422623/2725810).

Here is the relevant portion of my init file (there is nothing before this portion):

```
(require 'cl)

;; Org-mode that was shipped with Emacs
(setq load-path (remove-if (lambda (x) (string-match-p "org$" x)) load-path))
;; ELPA
(setq load-path (remove-if (lambda (x) (string-match-p "org-20" x)) load-path))

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/org-20150803")

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(require 'org)
```

How do I get Emacs to load the new version of `org-mode`?

UPDATE: I renamed `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/org` to be `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/org1`, so `Emacs` for sure cannot see the built-in version. However, it still shows the old version number!..

Comment: check M-x list-load-path-shadows

Comment: The output of this command is: `No Emacs Lisp load-path shadowings were found.` But please see the update at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you start over by deleting any personally installed versions of org:

```
rm -rf ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-* # your installation path _may_ vary.
```

and then

- **ensure that when you build org from elpa you have not already loaded org.**
- **decide which version of org you want and the package archive from which it comes.**

For instance, if you, like me, want org-plus-contrib from http://orgmode.org/elpa, first you should:

```
> emacs -Q -batch -eval "(progn (require 'package) (add-to-list 'package-archives '(\"org\" . \"http://orgmode.org/elpa/\"))  (package-initialize) (package-refresh-contents) (package-install 'org-plus-contrib))"
```

Then, confirm success by quitting emacs and restarting as:

```
> emacs -q -eval "(progn (require 'package) (package-initialize))" 
meta-x org-version
```

Notes:

- if you do NOT include `-eval "(progn (require 'package) (package-initialize))"` then org-version will likely be autoloaded from whatever you have installed in .../site-lisp - probably an old version
- regular 'org package is also available at http://orgmode.org/elpa - c.f. http://orgmode.org/elpa.html for differences

Comment: This advice worked. Note that you need to have `MELPA` loaded to install `org` and that `org-version` works only when `org-mode` is loaded. Also, for some reason, I get the message `Done (Total of 112 files compiled, 4 skipped)` when installing `org`, which seems to imply some compilation errors. However, all in all the new version shows. Thanks!

Comment: How do I do this with GUI Emacs? (Homebrew Emacs 24.5 on OSX.) When I do `open -a /Applications/Emacs.app --args --no-init  --eval "(progn (require 'package) (add-to-list 'package-archives '(\"org\" . \"http://orgmode.org/elpa/\"))  (package-initialize) (package-refresh-contents) (package-install 'org-plus-contrib))"` it never gets past `Contacting host: orgmode.org:80`. When I try eval-ing package.el first, I get `package-desc-reqs accessing a non-package-desc` and I can't install `org-plus-contrib`. Any suggestions?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on my MacOSX (non-homebrew) emacs 24.5-1 from http://emacsformacosx.com/ .   @incandescentman - assuming you are able to to otherwise use the package manager, I recommend you try fresh emacs.

Comment: This worked for me -- or rather, it made me realize that I was setting some `org-babel` stuff before calling `package-initialize` in my `.emacs`. I can only guess this triggered the old, default version of org-mode to be used. This was driving me nuts! Thanks.